# How to fix this error cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Student)'

Tags: swift

I'm trying to solve a problem in hackerrank that says:

> Write a program to store the details of 5 students.- Roll number, name, marks of 3 subjects
>
> You can give the deatails as below:
>
> var s1 = Student(rollNo:1, name:"Alan",mark1:1.45,mark2:2.50,mark3:3.43)
>      var s2 = Student(rollNo:1, name:"Ben",mark1:1.448,mark2:2.50,mark3:3.32)...
>
> You need to fetch the roll no of student s1.

I createad an struct with rollNo, name and mark1, mark2, mark3 and then I read from STDIN. But when I try to write the result it throws me that error. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
struct Student {
    var rollNo: Int
    var name: String
    var mark1: Double
    var mark2: Double
    var mark3: Double
}

let fileName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["OUTPUT_PATH"]!
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: fileName, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileName)!

guard let roll = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!) else { fatalError("Bad input") }

guard let n = readLine() else { fatalError("Bad input") }

guard let m1 = Double((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!) else { fatalError("Bad input") }

guard let m2 = Double((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!) else { fatalError("Bad input") }

guard let m3 = Double((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!) else { fatalError("Bad input") }

let result = Student(rollNo: roll, name: n, mark1: m1, mark2: m2, mark3: m3)

fileHandle.write(String(result).data(using: .utf8)!)
fileHandle.write("\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Comment: You can't do `String(result)` since `String` has no `init` method that takes a `Student` argument.

Comment: So do I need to add an `init` ?  @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error because you are trying to convert an object to a string.

String() doesn't support that in swift but you can implement the **CustomStringConvertable** protocol and get a similar result

**Change your model to look something like this:**

```
struct Student: CustomStringConvertible {

    var rollNo: Int
    var name: String
    var mark1: Double
    var mark2: Double
    var mark3: Double

    ///Change this to how you want your output to be formatted.
    var description: String { return "name: \(name) rollNumber: \(rollNo) mark1: \(mark1) mark2: \(mark2) mark3: \(mark3)"}
}
```

**Now to write this student object to a file you can do this:**

```
fileHandle.write(result.description.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Comment: That works partially, now it compiles without errors, but now hackerrank says, runtime error, output hidden, I think hacker rank sucks!

Comment: Does it want you to output the student object as a string? Or some other type?

Comment: I really don't know, the description of the problem I wrote above, is everything that hackerrank describes.